# A folder cannot be deleted

Tags: partitioning, directory, disk, error-handling

Recently my windows 8 crashed so from the ubuntu I had to remove all the filesystem files which were in Windows `C` partition. But I am not able to delete one folder, `Program Files (x86)`.

I am using this command to try and remove the folder:

```
sudo rm -rf
```

I am getting this error:

```
userdata: Error removing file: Directory not empty
userdata: Error removing file: Directory not empty
```

And for the folder `/USERS/WINDOWS` I am getting this error:

```
Local: Error removing file: Directory not empty
Local: Error removing file: Directory not empty
Local: Error removing file: Directory not empty
Local: Error removing file: Directory not empty
SRU000BF.log: Error removing file: No such file or directory
SRU000C0.log: Error removing file: No such file or directory
SRU000C0.log: Error removing file: Directory not empty
{533a67eb-9fb5-473d-b884-958cf4b9c4a3}: Error removing file: Directory not empty
{533a67eb-9fb5-473d-b884-958cf4b9c4a3}: Error removing file: Directory not empty
{533a67eb-9fb5-473d-b884-958cf4b9c4a3}: Error removing file: Directory not empty
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.003: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.001: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.etl: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.002: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.005: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.006: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.008: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.007: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKK~1.006: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.004: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.009: Error removing file: No such file or directory
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.009: Error removing file: Directory not empty
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.009: Error removing file: Directory not empty
ASHOKKRISHNA_kerberos_1_6_2_9200_0_0__100_6_2_9200_16384__win8_rtm_120725_1247_.009: Error removing file: Directory not empty
```

Comment: What command have you tried?

Comment: i used sudo rm -rf that folder

Comment: have you tried sudo rm -Rf folder instead of rm -rf folder (capital R).
Also why dont you just format or delete your C drive

Comment: no i have important files in it

Comment: no i just tried rm -rf only.

Comment: when i tried debugfs for that C partition i got bad magic number in superblock while opening

Answer (score 0):

Install `ntfs-3g` by following command :

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

Then run the `ntfsfix` command on your NTFS partition.

For example:

```
ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

Then try removing folders

```
sudo rm -rf folder
```

or

```
sudo rm -Rf folder
```

Comment: now also iam getting same problem the folder cannont deleted.